# Laptop overheating on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: fan, overheating, temperature

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on ASUS Rog GL702VM as a second OS along with  Windows 10. After several days on Ubuntu, I have noticed overheating. It seemed like my fan is not speeding up when the temperature is rising. However, when I am working on Windows 10, FAN is automatically adjusting speed depending on the temperature.

Then I did an experiment: I used Ubuntu for 20 minutes, and after overheating started, I switched to Windows. After that, my fan started adjusting speed.

Comment: What temperature do you consider overheating? Maybe just the thresholds are set differently? Can you check at what temperature fan starts in Windows? Is temperature in Linux over 70C without fan turning?

Answer (score 0):

Overheating is not uncommon in Ubuntu.

You can try using [TLP](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html). It’s a daemon that is pre-configured to reduce overheating as well as improve battery life. You just need to install TLP and restart your system. It will be auto-start at each boot and keep on running in the background.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw
```

If you are using ThinkPads, you require an additional step:

```
sudo apt install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms
```

Restart your system after installation.